# problem with sprintf implementation via pointers

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

Im trying to Write a function that takes a buffer, a format string and three void pointers to values and composes a string with the same text that would be printed if format was used on printf. the values being pointed at should replace the 3 placeholders in the format string.
i started to code only for cases of `%c` placeholder and it has a lot of errors(void value not ignored as it ought to be,dereferencing `void *` pointer) probably the main function is also problematic:

**EDIT:**

I've changed some of the code thanks to the responders, and now i'm getting this as the buffer value:

> **you have � dollars and also your name is � and your letter is �**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int format_to_string(char *buffer, char *format, void *arg1, void *arg2, void
*arg3);
int main(){
char format[20] = "%c bla %c bla %c";
char v1='5'; 
char v2 ='c';
char v3 = 'F';
void *arg1 = &v1;
void *arg2 = &v2;
void *arg3 = &v3;
char str[20];
char *buffer = str;
format_to_string(buffer,format, &arg1, &arg2,&arg3);
printf("%s",buffer);
return 0;

}
int format_to_string(char *buffer, char *format, void *arg1, void *arg2, void
*arg3)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0; *format != '\0'; format++, buffer++ )
    {
        if( *format != '%')
        {
            *buffer = *format;
        }
        else
        {
            format++;
            if(*format == 'c')
            {
                if(counter == 0)
                {
                    *buffer =*(char*)arg1;
                    counter++;
                    continue;
                }
                if(counter == 1)
                {
                    *buffer =*(char*)arg2;
                    counter++;
                    continue;
                }
                if(counter == 2)
                {
                    *buffer =*(char*)arg3;
                    counter++;
                    continue;
                }
            }    
        }

    }   
    *buffer = '\0';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And those errors would be...?

Comment: @ScottHunter dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer , void value not ignored as it ought to be, and of course Segmentation fault (core dumped) when i try to run it.

Comment: You have `char *buffer` so `*buffer = *arg1;` should be `*buffer = *(char *)arg1;`

Comment: It seems you're passing a non-zero terminated buffer to `printf`. Your `format_to_string` is incomplete, which is ok, but it does not add a zero terminator before exiting. Depending on what is there in memory after the end of `str[80]` you're most likely getting an output of some random characters and then undefined behavior. Also, check your assignments to buffer locations. The pointers you pass are `void *` and void does not specify a size of the the object it points to,so you need to cast each parameter according to what your format character indicates.

Comment: @yossman Does your format string have only `%c` in it, and the parameters all take the addresses of char type variables? You're still not adding a zero-terminator before exiting.

Comment: @DNT thank u for the kind response. for now, only '%c' are in the format string and in the parameters as well. i edited the code and tried to follow your lead, but it still gives me random chars as u said.

Answer (score 0):

This call,

`format_to_string(buffer,format, &arg1, &arg2,&arg3);`

passes the addresses of the three *pointers* to your variables, not the addresses of the variables themselves.

Change it to,

`format_to_string(buffer,format, &v1, &v2, &v3);`

or

`format_to_string(buffer,format, arg1, arg2, arg3);`

and try again.